# Cut a string after certain a specific character, but just one field

Tags: linux, bash, devops

This is from a vhost file. This is the output I get
 ServerName uat3-dam-something1.prg-dc.brb.com

Hello, 
I'm wondering how to cut from this output so only this part remains

```
 something1.prg-dc.brb.com
```

Keep in mind that "something" could be "something4141411" or "something23". So length operations won't work. Tried with cut command and AWK, but didn't work. I would be happy receive a tips from the bash experts :)

Comment: What parts of the input are fixed versus variable?

Comment: Seems that `something[0-9]+\.` is the only fixed part, just an assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
echo "ServerName uat3-dam-something1.prg-dc.brb.com" |cut -d\- -f3-4
```

Will return:

```
something1.prg-dc.brb.com
```

And if you change the string (as you mention):

```
echo "ServerName uat3-dam-something111111.prg-dc.brb.com" |cut -d\- -f3-4
```

It will keep returning:

```
something111111.prg-dc.brb.com
```

Comment: Works but can u explain?

Comment: Sure. By specifying `cut -d\- -f3-4` what I am doing is to set the `-` character as delimiter for my string and `3-4` the fields I want the command to show, filtering the rest of the string. That said, it just matches the given string "ServerName uat3-dam-something.prg-dc.brb.com", because `-f1` would be `ServerName uat3`, `-f2` would be `dam`, `-f3` would be `something.prg` and `-f4` would be `dc.brb.com`.

Answer (score 4):

Like this :

```
grep -o 'something.*' file
```

or more specific:

```
grep -oE 'something[0-9]+\..*' file
```

### Output:

```
something1.prg-dc.brb.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with provided samples only.

```
awk -F'uat3-dam-' '{print $NF}' Input_file
```

***Description:*** Making `uat3-dam-` as field separator and printing last field of it.

---

---

***2nd solution:***

```
awk 'match($0,/something.*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ echo 'ServerName uat3-dam-something1.prg-dc.brb.com' | awk -F- '{sub(".*" $2 FS,"")}1'
something1.prg-dc.brb.com
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
echo "ServerName uat3-dam-something1.prg-dc.brb.com" | sed -E 's/.*(something.*)/\1/'
```

Or, if the string is in a file named `file`

```
sed -E 's/.*(something.*)/\1/' file
```

Explanation:

- `-E` is for extended regex
- `.*(something.*)` means "any char 0 or more times followed by `something` and any other char 0 or more times".
- `\1` is used to print only the matching part inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use :

```
echo ${test#*dam-}
```

Example :

```
test="ServerName uat3-dam-something1.prg-dc.brb.com"
echo ${test#*dam-}
```

which gives:

```
something1.prg-dc.brb.com
```

Note that the opposite version would be `echo ${test%something*}`